# Alien Mind Control Novel - 1960s

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely recall a novel from the 1960s. Alien invasion of Earth where the aliens had mind control. The hero was immune somehow and lived in an old missile silo. Does this ring a bell?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.